# Windows 10 - MAMP Pro - MySQL Issue

Tags: windows, mamp

I recently installed MAMP Pro demo version on my Windows 10 and my issue is that mysql is not running, even if green light is on.

**My setup:**
Using multiple versions of PHP, 5.4.45 and 7.1.5.
locahost has 7.1.5
.dev domains have 5.4.45

Using default ports: 80, 443 and 3306

**Issues:**

- I can not connect with databases on .dev domains, says Error
  establishing a database connection.
- I can not connect with mysql through command line, says Error 2003,
  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).
- I can not change MySQL password from MAMP says, can not update please
  check if mysql is running. But both Apache and MySQL have green
  light. But when I open XAMPP Netstat I only see that port 80 is being
  used and not port 3306. PHP is also running.

**Other information:**

- I can start Xampp MySQL with no problem while MAMP is also running.
  But XAMPP can not connect to Apache.
- I can open phpMyAdmin, but in Server section is only showing port number. Server: .:3306.
- Before It
  worked fine, but somehow I messed up and now I can not connect to mysql.

Send help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Uncheck "Local access only to MySQL database" under MySQL settings.